# How to count number of replacements made in string

Tags: python

I am currently working on a beginner problem 
(https://www.reddit.com/r/beginnerprojects/comments/1i6sax/challenge_count_and_fix_green_eggs_and_ham/).

The challenge is to read through a file, replacing lower case 'i' with 'I' and writing a new corrected file.

I am at a point where the program reads the input file, replaces the relevant lower case characters, and writes a new corrected file.  However, I need to also count the number of corrections.

I have looked through the .replace() documentation and I cannot see that it is possible to find out the number of replacements made.  Is it possible to count corrections using the replace method?

```py
def capitalize_i(file):
    file = file.replace('i ', 'I ')
    file = file.replace('-i-', '-I-')
    return file


with open("green_eggs.txt", "r") as f_open:
    file_1 = f_open.read()

file_2 = open("result.txt", "w")

file_2.write(capitalize_i(file_1))
```

Comment: How about using a `file.count()` before replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the count function:

```
i_count = file.count('i ')
file = file.replace('i ', 'I ')
i_count += file.count('-i-')
file = file.replace('-i-', '-I-')
```

`i_count` will have the total amount of replacements made. You can also separate them by creating new variables if you want.

Comment: `"one two tree one".count('one')` - You are right. It work as he need.